# kableExtra save equation to png or jpg

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

I'm trying to save a `kableExtra` table to a png that contains an equation.

A really simple example:

```r
tab <- kable("$a^2$")
tab
```

which gives me the table I'm looking for:

[image]

Now I want to save this to a png or jpg file with `save_kable`

`save_kable(tab, file = "test.jpg")`

which then returns this:

[image]

I have already tried changing the `escape` argument but the result remains the same

```r
tab <- kable("$a^2$", escape = TRUE)
tab <- kable("$a^2$", escape = FALSE)
```

Any ideas how to make sure the png or jpg file also renders the equation/mathsymbols?

Thanks!

Comment: It's related to this: https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/578

Comment: Thanks, I added a comment there that I have the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

I propose one solution based on two other packages:

```
library(knitr)
library(gridExtra) # to display a table
library(latex2exp) # for TeX function which transform $$ to expression

png("test.png")
grid.table(TeX(kable("$a^2$", format = "simple")))
dev.off()
```

`escape` will work only for colnames in `kable()`.

Comment: Thanks for providing that workaround!! Very helpful. 
Of course it'd be nice if the formatting of the `kable`  were to be retained